# Faulting module name: dts.dll, version: 2009.100.1600.1, time stamp: 0x4bb679b7 Exception code: 0xc0000005

Tags: c#, ssis, fault

I have created one application and running SSIS Package dynamically.

But while running the code Application got crashed.I saw eventviewer and found below exception

```
"Faulting module name: dts.dll, version: 2009.100.1600.1, time stamp: 0x4bb679b7 Exception code: 0xc0000005"..
```

Please help me to fix this..

```
DtsRunTime.Application app = new DtsRunTime.Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(packageName, null, true);

        //set package varaibles
        DtsRunTime.Variables vars = pkg.Variables;
        IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> varEnumarators = variablesMap.GetEnumerator();
        while (varEnumarators.MoveNext())
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, object> item = varEnumarators.Current;
            if (item.Value.ToString().Contains("@LoopCompanyId"))
                vars[item.Key].Value = ReplaceParmeterValue(item.Value.ToString());
            else
            {
                vars[item.Key].Value = item.Value;
            }

        }

        //Application got crashed while executing this line of code
        return pkg.Execute();
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to troubleshoot this issue? Is there any logging occurring within the SSIS package?

Comment: I dont get any exception.Application gets crashed while executing
pkg.Execute() method.Same pavakge is running fine when I run form SSSM.